# Kanboard Docker SSL

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, kanban

I want to deploy the [kanboard](https://kanboard.org/) docker image. Everything runs fine so far on port 80. Now I want to make it accessable only with https. I have custom Certificates. There are four files: *.cer, *.csr, *.pfx, *.key 
How do I configure the docker container (nginx) to be accessable with my own SSL certificates?

```
docker run -d --restart always \
-v kanboard_data:/var/www/app/data \
-v kanboard_plugins:/var/www/app/plugins \
-v kanboard_ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl \
--name kanboard -p 443:443 -t kanboard/kanboard:latest
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Simply copy your certificate and private key to the /etc/nginx/ssl/ directory of your docker image.  You can do this in your Dockerfile.  Here's mine (this is the whole Dockerfile for me - 3 lines were all I needed)

```
FROM kanboard/kanboard
COPY <path/to/whatever.cer> /etc/nginx/ssl/kanboard.crt
COPY <path/to/whatever.key> /etc/nginx/ssl/kanboard.key
```

Make sure you change the  arguments to reflect where your certificate and private key are on your development machine.

The official docker image for Kanboard comes with an [Nginx server](https://helpdesk.ssls.com/hc/en-us/articles/203427642-How-to-install-a-SSL-certificate-on-a-NGINX-server).  If you look at the Nginx configuration file at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf in your docker image, you will see that it already contains these lines:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/kanboard.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/kanboard.key;
```

This is where I got the 2nd argument for each COPY instruction in the Dockerfile.  I didn't have to modify nginx.conf at all.

Once I added the above COPY instructions to my Dockerfile all I had to do was re-build the image then run it and now I have https access to my server.